# Port Forwarding a Minecraft Server with Netgear Genie

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have already made a Minecraft server of my own but it runs on Hamachi and my friends can connect to my network but can't connect to the server I made!  I want to be able to set up a server that can be connected to without any programs like Hamachi though.  I know how to do this but I get stuck on the part where you have to add a port for your server on your router's website.  I can't find the section where I add ports!  By the way my router's website is Netgear Genie.  Can anyone help me find this section?

Comment: Without being familiar with Netgear Genie, no. I would assume it's somewhere under Router Settings, in a section called Port Forwarding. Keep in mind that you'll need the address of the server (usually 192.168.0.something), which is listed in a section called something like Connected Devices.

Comment: The thing is it is actually a website where you add the port.  I have seen other people do it with different Netgear routers but none with mine.

Comment: The answer to this question would be identical is the program being port-forwarded was something other than a game. Thus, this question is off-topic on Arqade and I am flagging it for closure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about port forwarding and not about gaming.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**
Go to "routerlogin.net" and enter your username and password. Your router comes with a password and username; I use Netgear Genie and my default username/pass was:

```
 Username: admin
 Password: password
```

For some people, the password is "123456789". Review the manual that came with the router if neither of these passwords work.

**Step 2**
There should be a tab towards the general top of the page saying "Advanced." Click on that, and then click on "Advanced Setup" towards the left of the page. Now, click on "Port Forwarding/Port Triggering."

**Step 3**
Click "Add Custom Service". *If you don't see it, try scrolling down.*

Enter the following information:

```
 Service Name: Minecraft Server
 Service Type: TCP/UDP
 External Starting Port: 25565
 External Ending Port: 25565
```

Make sure that the checkmark is checked for the option "*Use the same port range for Internal port.*"

For the Internal IP Address, click the circle next to your computer.

**Step 4**
Click "Apply". [Click here](http://www.whatsmyip.us/) to find what your External IP is. Tell your friends to enter your External IP in the Server Address when adding your server to their server list.

It should be like this for them:

```
 Server name: <This can be anything they want>
 Server Address: XX.XX.XXX.XXX
```

The "X"'s should be replaced with the numbers you got from the link I provided.
Obviously, they won't be able to connect if you don't turn on the server.

If you need more help, [Click Here.](http://portforward.com/)
If you have questions, comment and I'll be glad to help some more.

Comment: Wait its still not working

Comment: Would I enter my normal ip into the Server file or the enternal one?  When I enter the enternal one it doesn't work.

Comment: @EthanBacon I'm assuming by "Server file" you mean the one called "server.properties"? Just leave the part that says "Server IP:" blank. For some reason, if you type anything there, it messes up the server D: And for "Server-Port", make sure that is "25565".

Comment: Wait why can't I use the external IP to connect to the server but I can still connect by using localhost in direct connect?  Cam other people still connect with my enternal IP?

Comment: @EthanBacon Localhost allows you to connect to your own router. So say at home you have 2 computers; one with a server, one with Minecraft. As long as they are connected to the same Wi-Fi, "localhost" can be used to connect to the server.                                                    Go to http://www.canyouseeme.org/ and enter "25565" for the "port" area. Then tell me what it says.

Comment: okay I will do that.

Comment: It says it can't see it because my connection has timed out.  I am assuming this means no server for me...

Comment: Hm, sometimes it's not always accurate. Try making a new server and running the .exe (or .jar) but don't change anything in server.properties. Run the server and try connecting to it.

Comment: With the enternal IP?

Comment: @EthanBacon Yes, but I believe you mean EXternal IP

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9453/discussion-between-avestar101-and-ethan-bacon)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there isn't a firewall blocking communications on your server PC. Make sure that the server port (usually 25565) is being forwarded to the correct internal IP address. It may help to make the server PC have a 'static' IP (not assigned by DHCP) otherwise if it changes, the port forwarding will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

According to [How is Port-Fowarding configured](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20917/~/how-is-port-forwarding-configured%3F), you should first log into your Netgear Genie by going to http://www.routerlogin.net. Then enter the username (`admin`) and the default password (either `password` or `1234`). On the top, switch to the Advanced tab and click Advanced Setup in the side. Hit Port Forwarding / Port Triggering.

Underneath "Please select the service type", select "Port Forwarding", and in the drop-down for "Service Name" select Minecraft (if this entry does not exist see below). In the boxes that say "Server IP Address", type the IP of the computer in which you are running the server from. You're done once you hit Apply.

---

If you weren't able to select Minecraft from the drop down as said above, hit "Add Custom Service". For Service Name, type Minecraft Server, and have the protocol as TCP/UDP. The ports aware both 25565. The internal IP address is your IP. Hit Apply and you're done!